# Why would adding an index on a MySQL table slow it down significantly but ok on SQL Server and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql, performance, query-performance

Version MySQL 5.7.2

I'm working with dummy data with int columns.

time: 1-10mm

products: 70,000 random ints with another 30,000 that are dupes from the 70,000

volume:  ranges from 500 - 1000

price:  ranges from 10 - 50 though the price stays within bounds of 1-5 diff for each product row data.

from the above, 10mm rows are created by randomly selecting a product and generating the required  row data

running a range query like...

```
select * from productdata where product >= 1500 and product <= 2000
```

takes about 4 seconds.

When I add an index on product using...

```
create index productindex on productdata(product)
```

The query now takes about 30 seconds.  Time is the only unique column in the table but setting that as the primary key does not help either.

On SQL Server and PostgreSQL I don't see the same issues with the same data and query using a non clustered index in each.  I only really have experience with writing queries for SQL Server so a bit perplexed by this.   I tried PostgreSQL as well to have another db to compare to.

All databases are the latest stable versions available.

Action Output (I had to decrease the range as the original query was taking too long)...

[image: Action Output]

Without Index..

[image: Without Index]

With Index..

[image: With index]

Table status...

[image: table status]

Buffer...

[image]

Explain Select...

[image]

Show create table...

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `productindex` (`product`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Trying with time and product as key...

[image]

Comment: Also add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE productdata;` and the version of MySQL (is it 5.7 or something else?)

Comment: I've added what you guys asked for.  It's version 6.3

Comment: There is no version 6.3 of MySQL. 5.7 is the latest GA release. 8.0 is a release candidate

Comment: Sorry 5.7.  I gave the version of workbench

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM?  InnoDB?  What is the cache size?  (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`)  Did you run the query a second time (to cancel out the affect of caching)?  Do you have `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)  How much RAM?  How big (GB) is the table (`SHOW TABLE STATUS`).

<strike>*Probably*...</strike>  *Definitely*... The cache for the *data* was not large enough to hold the products in question.  And, since the products are mostly "random", there is a lot of I/O.

Here's what happens in *any*(?) database vendor for that query:

1. Locate the 'row' for 1500 in the index.
2. Scan forward through the index until 2000.  (Due to BTree organization in MySQL, this is quite efficient.)
3. For each row, reach over into the "data" to get all the columns (`SELECT *`).  (This is where vendors vary.  And "Engines" in MySQL will vary.)  Since the data rows are in one order, but the index rows are in a different order, MySQL will be effectively doing 'random I/O' to get the rows.  (MySQL fetches the rows as needed.  Other vendors may sort the row-addresses first -- perhaps a benefit, perhaps a cost.)
4. For MySQL with InnoDB and large TEXT/BLOB columns, those columns *may* be stored elsewhere, thereby necessitating an extra I/O.  (Hence the admonition not to use `*`, but to spell out only the necessary columns.)

But...

If "too much" of the table needs to be fetched -- in particular more than about 20% of the table has `product` in the desired range -- MySQL will do a table scan *instead of using the index*.  (I don't know about non-MySQL vendors.)  This optimization is *usually* beneficial, but sometimes is a mistake.  The `EXPLAIN SELECT ..` would tell us which it did.

InnoDB "reaches into the data" via the `PRIMARY KEY` which is "clustered" with the data.  So it is a BTree-probe to find each row.  MyISAM has a byte address into the data file, so it is a `fseek`.  Other vendors work differently.

So... Is the comparison "fair"?  Do you have the PK "clustered" with the data on all vendor tests?  (Etc)

And I did not get into the caching details.  This is probably a major component of the slowdown.

I'll fill in more details after you provide more details.

**After details**

You are using InnoDB, not MyISAM (good).  `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8M` is *much*  too small.  For 16GB of RAM, recommend `11G`.  But even 1G would show a significant speedup since the table is smaller than that.

You say you are running MySQL 5.7, yet the 8M default contradicts that.  Did you override the default?  Please provide the version (`SELECT @@version;`).

It seems that there are no big `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns, so my comments on such do not apply.

Bottom line:  To get a 'fair' comparison, increase the buffer_pool setting for MySQL.  This is the most important tunable for performance.  It is not automatically set because it depends on the amount of *available* RAM.

Comment: The default on Postgressql is non clustered which should be the same as MySQL.  I've added the details you've asked for.

Comment: Running on my desktop so 16gb ram

Comment: Postgres doesn't have clustered indexes. All tables are heaps in Postgres. In MySQL all InnoDB tables are clustered, no heaps.

Comment: @pad11 your table doesn't have any primary key or unique constraint. Why? Creating a `PRIMARY KEY` that matches the query (say `(product, time)` if that combination is unique) would improve performance of the query - in addition of the buffer pool changes that Rick advised.

Comment: Yes, the ultimate improvement would be to have the PK _start with_ `product`.  This is because of the "clustering" of the PK with the data.

Comment: So, if you don't give Postgres a big enough cache, it will be I/O-bound?

Comment: @ypercube - i mentioned non clustered.  Can't you do this for clustered (with limitations) "CLUSTER [VERBOSE] table_name [ USING index_name ]"

Comment: i had tried with just key as time and the same index.  i'll try now with both but still confused on why the others don't have the same issue.

Comment: I added the results...at the bottom.  just 1 sec quicker than without the key

Comment: I just noticed the buffer comments.  i'll try that too

Comment: 5.7.2 is the version im using...updated that too

Comment: I increased the pool size to 3G.  It's definitely faster now but still not as fast without the key / index.  About 8 seconds vs 5.  "By default, SQL Server dynamically grows and shrinks the size of its buffer pool" - so MySQL won't do this?

Comment: @pad11 - 5.7.2 was a pre-release version;  recommend you go with GA -- 5.7.7 or later.

Comment: @pad11 - MySQL's buffer_pool does not shrink.  It is wise to give it as much RAM as you can afford after all other things are taken into account.  (70% of _available_ RAM is _usually_ good.)

Comment: @pad11 the image you posted shows you made (time, product) the PK. I suggested with the reverse order. The order of columns in indexes matter. As Rick mentioned, if the PK starts with `product` then the table is "clustered" on product.

Comment: @RickJames I installed from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  Yea, I meant to do it the other way around.

Comment: But it seems like increasing the buffer size to 11G made a big difference.  Is it safe to assume that the other two database servers are handling the buffer size automatically while mysql doesn't?  Seems odd to have the buffer size set to such a small number as default

Comment: @pad11 - I am struggling to figure out how you got 8M -- That was the default until about a _decade_ ago.  5.7 has a default of 128M, which is "too small" for _most_ machines today.  (I don't know about SQL Server, Postgres, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

buffer pool is small,Set larger values。

`SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=402653184;
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;
select * from productdata where product >= 1500 and product <= 2000`

Comment: Could you clarify how this differs from Rick James' answer? And, will this permanently modify the buffer size, or just for the current session?